# i have a question about this problem. (SLPC 2004 repeatless)

Tags: python

[image]

### i have 2 codes. i don't know how to calculate time

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt')

ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]+[0]*999991
number = 10
k = 10
while True:
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    if n == 0:
        break

    while ls[999999] == 0:
        a = str(number)
        if len(set(a)) != len(a):
            number += 1

            continue


        ls[k-1] = number
        k += 1
        number += 1
    print(ls[n-1])
```

---

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt')

ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
number = 10
while True:
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    if n == 0:
        break

    while len(ls) <= n-1:
        a = str(number)
        if len(set(a)) != len(a):
            number += 1
            continue


        ls.append(number)

        number += 1
    print(ls[n-1])
```

Both codes run out of time. What should I do to save time?
pleas, help me

memory limit is 128 MB
i think checking dupliacation code has something wrong...

Comment: Use `time` module

Comment: @PCM If only it had a `save()` method :-). I suspect they misspoke when they said calculate time and didn't when they said "save time".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through all integers and filtering out those with repetitions, you could just go through permutations of digits so you don't need to filter. (Ok ok, I'm filtering out (really skipping) the numbers with leading zeros, but that's far less.)

```
from itertools import permutations, dropwhile, chain, islice
import math

def numbers(digit_length):
    no_repetitions = permutations(range(10), digit_length)
    skip = math.perm(9, digit_length - 1)
    no_lead_zeros = islice(no_repetitions, skip, None)
    return no_lead_zeros

def solve(n):
    all_numbers = chain(*map(numbers, range(1, 11)))
    the_number = next(islice(all_numbers, n - 1, None))
    return int(''.join(map(str, the_number)))

print(solve(10000))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBLTsQwEET3OUXvxkZmNBEbQOIKXCEyk57Y4J/aHX6XD3ZipMTLqF@9qqQfNjE8PCZalhtFD5aROEaXwfoUiSEh@Zk12xiygpFi@jLWoYKr0TYosNnZK3bt2ms2XTfiDcLs35CyGO1keXAYJjbyuYPyQhwIE7JdQ@Hl4BCkw4Siv8hi27Mrmj9sKkDVnCslno5XcA@9/Jc41OPwixSrY@spjm61Bip4jQE3jJBnCkd6G5Sj@yx826CdG9rEEr7@C3HndRLto4K2Q0HfS7mFs8EGFSbgN4vWapemINQRrdOhlA0sTqfzeyyuqspMapdZLV2ierV17S/lSbksfw)):

```
26057
```